# NSURL is null while NSString is correct in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have an `NSString` containing a url and when I allocate `NSURL` with the `NSString`, NSURL outputs (null). It's because there are some illegal characters in the url, which `NSURL` can't read without encoding the `NSString` containing the url.

```
NSString *u = [incomingUrlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];

NSLog(@"INCOMINGURLSTRING: %@" , u);
NSLog(@"URL: %@" , url);
```

**Output is:**

```
 INCOMINGURLSTRING: /url/path/fileName_blå.pdf
 URL: (null)
```

incomingUrlString contains the Norwegian letter "å", which I think is the reason for the `NSURL` being (null)

I also tried this:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [file stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)trimmedString, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

NSLog(@"TRIMMEDSTRING: %@" , trimmedString);
NSLog(@"ENCODEDSTRING: %@" , [encodedString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

NSLog(@"URL: %@" , url);
```

**Here the output is:**

```
 TRIMMEDSTRING: /url/path/fileName_blå.pdf
 ENCODEDSTRING: /url/path/fileName_blå.pdf
 URL: %2Furl%2FPath%2FfileName_bl%C3%A5.pdf
```

My goal is to load the URL into a `UIWebView`. It works for all the other incoming urls except for this one, they all look the same except for the filename. This is the only one containg an illegal character. But I have to find a way to encode this, because there will be more files containg either "æ", "ø" or "å" in the future.

I know the output does not look correct according to url standards, which I did on purpose. I can't show the correct url with http://blah blah because of security reasons.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: instead of stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method you're using for percent-encoding the characters in the string also escapes legal URL characters. This would be appropriate if you were encoding a URL parameter, in this case though it would be better to simply use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` because it leaves the characters that are part of the URL's structure (':', '/', etc.) intact:

```
NSString *u = @"http://example/path/fileName_blå.pdf";
u = [u stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
NSLog(@"%@", url); // http://example.com/path/fileName_bl%C3%A5.pdf
```

Comment: No, it's not; in your first code snippet you're calling `stringByReplacingPercentEscapes...`. You would use this with a string that already has percent escapes in it, but you actually want the opposite here, `stringByAddingPercentEscapes...`.

Comment: Haha oh my goodness, I'm so sorry! I read it wrong, but yes, you are right. It fixed my problem, thank you so much!

Comment: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 - Use -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: instead

Answer (score 2):

If you have an URL that is a file path you must use `+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path`. For the `URLWithString:` method the String must contain a scheme like `file://` or `http://`.

Comment: I know, that's not the problem. That's why I wrote it works for all the other incoming urls. The urls look the same, except for the filename.

Answer (score 1):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated.

The new way (iOS 7+) to do it is:

```
NSString *encoded = [raw stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet];
```

File path is defined by https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089.
The key part is to allow characters `.` and `/` and disallow `%`. `CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed` fits the requirements.

Output with your example:

> incomingString: /url/path/fileName_blå.pdf
> encodedString:  /url/path/fileName_bl%C3%A5.pdf
> URL:            /url/path/fileName_bl%C3%A5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I found also that for some North European characters, NSISOLatin1StringEncoding fits better.

```
- (void) testEncoding {
    NSString * urlString = @"http://example/path/fileName_blå.pdf";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
}
```