# iOS: NSString loses URL, (null) is shown

Tags: ios, xcode, url, nsstring, null

This is my Code so far:

```
NSString *listedImageURL = listedProduct.image;

NSLog(@"URL: %@", listedImageURL);
```

This Code works fine and NSLog shows me the correct URL. But when I try the following Code, NSLog shows up (null):

```
NSString *listedImageURL = listedProduct.image;

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:listedImageURL];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Are you trying to `NSLog` the `UIImage *image` or the `NSString *listedImageURL`?

Comment: Where do you have the NSLog that gives (null) and what does it look like?

Comment: thank you guys :) I tried it with NSURL, NSData and UIImage.. all is (null). only NSString gives me the URL.

Comment: Try to `NSLog` the URL using `NSLog(@"%@", [imageURL absoluteString]);`. It shows the right URL?

Comment: Alberto, this does not work..

Comment: Well, it's really weird. NSLogging the NSData results (null)?

Comment: yes it is weird :S.. when I put in a simple URL instead of `listedProduct.image`, it works perfectly. maybe the information that the url comes out of a xml file (but is perfectly shown in NSLog) could help to solve the problem. the code above is also in a cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: Did you tried to set the `UIImage *image` to some `UIImageView`?

Comment: no, but I already lose the URL in NSURL..

Comment: Actually, you don't lose it, @AlexisW. NSLogging the url using `[imageURL absoluteString]` it shows the right image. Try to set it to an UIImageView and see if it shows the image.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://coderepo.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/nslog-a-uiimageview-in-xcode-for-iphone-sdk/). The UIImage results (null), but when you set it to an UIImageView it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that relower is on the right track, the documentation states:

> This method expects URLString to contain any necessary percent escape codes, which are ‘:’, ‘/’, ‘%’, ‘#’, ‘;’, and ‘@’. Note that ‘%’ escapes are translated via UTF-8.

I believe that it would be helpful to identify which characters might be causing an issue for you if you were to post some examples of the URLs that you are converting.

I would suggest logging: listedImageURL

and then also running:

```
NSString *escapedImageUrl = [listedProduct.image stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then log that.

That should let you see what is being escaped and what is being missed. It can be something as simple as a stray space.

You could also try using NSASCIIStringEncoding instead of NSUTF8StringEncoding and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: yes, this works, but now my log looks like: %0A%0Ahttp://www.google.com/image.png :S

Comment: That's your problem. %0A is a Line Break. My guess is that when you're parsing your string you're including two line breaks on the front. Check how you read that string in and see if you can remove those. Do that and then the code @relower gave you below will probably work for you.

Comment: I parse the URL from a xml-file (`<image>http://www.google.com/image.png</image>`). there is no line break :S

Comment: They're coming from somewhere, my best guess is that the XML is not clean. I would suggest saving a copy of it and opening it up in a program like Notepad++ which will let you see the hidden control characters such as linebreaks.

You can test it yourself to see if that makes a difference. Instead of setting listedImageURL to be the variable from the XML, write it in manually using @"" notation. Then run the rest of your code and you'll probably find that it works.

Comment: hey keab42, I got it work :) look at this: `NSString *listedImageURL = [[listedProduct.image stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%0A" withString:@""];`

Answer (score 2):

it can be null, because of your string to url convertion.

Try this code below;

```
NSString *listedImageURL = [listedProduct.image stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:listedImageURL];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

will work for you i think. good luck.

Comment: thank you relower, but I can not agree to your answer. maybe the information that the url comes out of a xml file (but is perfectly shown in NSLog) could help to solve the problem. the code above is also in a cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: did you try the code which i writed?, if its not working, there is an other problem i think.

Comment: could you write here your url string please ?

Comment: also, you can check, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486435/nsurl-is-null-while-nsstring-is-correct-in-objective-c

Comment: i just want to see your "listedImageUrl", are you trying to get image from bundle or applications documents directory?