# Why isn't my app parsing the link correctly for video?

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, mpmovieplayercontroller

So I'm extremely new to coding in general (my background is in video production) and I've been tasked with creating an iPhone app.  Xcode has actually been pretty easy with tutorials and the like, but I've run into a brick wall of things outside of my knowledge. Anyway...here goes.

I followed a tutorial on YouTube about parsing XML in iOS.  Works great.  However, the tutorial parses the XML into labels.  That part works perfectly.  However, I'm attempting to parse a podcast RSS feed, using a custom made XML document, and I'd like the link to the video to go to a button that plays, rather than fill a label. So I assumed I could pass the link that's already working into a button that uses the MPMoviePlayerViewController.  Didn't work.

It gave an error about passing an NSString as a URL. I then used NSUrl to make the video link. No error, but the video doesn't play.  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

The only code I'm including is the DetailViewController.m file, as everything else works, even the link showing up correctly in the label.  It just doesn't connect to the button correctly.  When you tap the play button in the simulator, it launches the movie player and just shows the "Loading..." screen.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    #import "DetailViewController.h"
    #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

    @implementation DetailViewController
    @synthesize theList;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.title = theList.title;
        theTitle.text = theList.title;
        theAuthor.text = theList.author;
        playAudio.text = theList.audio;
        playVideo.text = theList.video;

    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {

        [super viewDidUnload];
    }

    - (IBAction)playVid:(id)sender {

        NSURL *playVid = [NSURL URLWithString:theList.video];

        MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:playVid];

        [mpViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];

        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

    }
    @end
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a valid NSURL instance out of the string?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't know how to check that.  I do know that the url is correct, as it is passed into the label correctly. Do you know of any tutorials addressing how to check what the NSURL is receiving?

Comment: add `NSLog(@"%@",playVid);` right after you create `playVid` and see what shows up in the console.

Comment: When I use  `NSLog(@"%@",playVid);` right after the  `playVid`, it spits out null. I added `NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theList.video];
    
    NSLog(@"string> %@ ", urlString);` before your suggestion and I see the link.  So it looks like some formatting is wrong somewhere? Maybe? Or I didn't set up the NSURL correctly?

Comment: Just for an update, I added a `stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding:nsasciistringencoding` to my NSUrl, and it spit out a %0A a the beginning of my link. So, based on some Googling, that is a line break at the beginning of the URL.  I checked the XML file, and there isn't a line break there. Is there a way to remove that in Xcode if it detects one?

Comment: So `theList.video` is not showing up as a string all by itself?  What is `theList.video` if you `NSLog` it?

Comment: It shows the correct link. But I was just now able to fix it by using `NSString *urlString = [[theList.video componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]` to remove any extra characters. Weird. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, at least a solution to make it work, in my case.

It looks like the parser I was using counted the line breaks outside of the tags I used in my XML file.  I removed them and it worked.  I also found this question on Stackoverflow:

[iOS: NSString loses URL, (null) is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851314/ios-nsstring-loses-url-null-is-shown)

I was able to solve it.  Thanks so much to H2CO3 and Justin Paulson for helping me figure out my NSURL was null.